# given the following equation system, find the max?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I realise that the question is not clear, but I'm not really sure what this problem  itself is all about. I have an "algorithm and analysis" mid exam coming up.

> ### Problem 4 (5 points)
>
> Consider the following equation system:
>
> max     x<sub>1</sub> + 4x<sub>2</sub> + 3x<sub>3</sub>
>
> x<sub>1</sub> + 4x<sub>2</sub> + 3x<sub>3</sub>     ≤     4

[image]

I think that I can solve this using dynamic programming, but I'm not sure... It looks a lot like a knapsack problem, but I'm not sure what I would consider as the value, and what as the weight...

Comment: Is there any other contraint on the variables, like being nonnegative integers? I find it a bit surprising that the objective function looks exactly the same as the constraint. Is this intentional? Is some specific method desired to systematically find an optimal solution?

Comment: Can you say what your course is about ? Because there are a lot of different ways to tackle this problem (it seems pretty much like [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) to me, or analysis of functions with several variables), and for your exam, I guess your teacher will expect an answer related to the course he/she has given.

Comment: The course is design of algorithms and analysis; the topics for mid exam are graphs and dynamic programming.. that's why I thought it was solvable by knapsadk.. but I don't know how to start from there

Comment: @coder there are no other constraint whatsoever.. but I would think a dynamic programming approach is desirable by our prof, since that's what we are being tested on

Comment: looks like it's continued on the next page

Comment: Can someone please verify my solution, I used knapsack by assuming that the coefficients are the weights and values; and the maximum weight is 4 .  https://imgur.com/a/WfXFzMg          I got a maximum value of 4, then to get the items we picked I do backtracking

Comment: The question in the image does not ask a question. It merely states "consider the following equation system". What does it ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the expression to maximise is *also* the expression that is constrained to an upper limit, you obviously need to solve this equation:

x<sub>1</sub> + 4x<sub>2</sub> + 3x<sub>3</sub> = 4

As you have more than one freedom (3 variables, 1 equation, so 2 dimensions of freedom), there are an infinite number of solutions.

You can pick *any* value for x<sub>2</sub> and x<sub>3</sub>, and then the corresponding x<sub>1</sub> is:

x<sub>1</sub> = 4 − 4x<sub>2</sub> − 3x<sub>3</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One obvious solution would be

```
x_1 = 0
x_2 = 1
x_3 = 0
```

which can be found by inspection; another one would be as follows.

```
x_1 = 1
x_2 = 0
x_3 = 1
```

Comment: I'd even add that all points of `{(x,y,z) in R^3 : x + 4y + 3z = 4}` do maximize the objective function.

Comment: I solved it using knapsack, by saying that weight(i)  = value (i)    as such ... :  https://imgur.com/a/WfXFzMg